# What kind of RAM stick is this?

Tags: ram, identify-this-card

[image]

Specifically, what are those two modules in the middle of each? I'm not too familiar with components this old. I've figured out that they're sticks of SEC SDRAM, but I've found nothing about any of the components. I also haven't seen any pictures of SDRAM with those two modules.
[image]

Comment: The ICs in the middle are claimed to be [buffers/bus drivers](https://www.omo-ic.com/chip/456/74fct162244ctpa-1190.html).  Easily searchable.

Comment: "this old"? Those probably come from a Pentium class machine. Around here, that should count as recent... ;-)

Comment: I know it's not "that" old I'm just young and didn't know how else to word it lol.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Despite the 144 pin DIMM form factor, this is **not** a SDRAM, but an EDO module with 16 MiB capacity.

The used RAM chips are

- KM48C2104 (KM48 marks RAMs)
- Manufactured by Samsung, of
- 16 MiBit Capacity
- EDO-RAMs, with
- 2Mi by 8 Organization and
- 60ns speed (the -6 marking)

They are **not** SDRAM, as such would be numbered as KM48**S**x with X being L for 66 MHz and H for 100 MHz.

The additional chips, [74FCT162244](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cy74fct162244t.pdf?) are 16 bit line driver, organized as 4 independent groups of 4 drivers each.

Comment: @truehd those drivers are quite nice the moment one notes their timing parameters :))

Comment: IDT stuff tends to be Quite Nice (and Not Cheap)

Comment: @MichaelGraf True, then again, those line drivers are rather generic, developed and manufactured by many suppliers.